# malloc(sizeof(struct xxxx)) isn't allocating any memory

Tags: c, memory-management, struct

I'm learning C using the [Learn C the Hard Way](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex17.html) online book, on exercise 17, and I've come across a confusing error. In the exercise, I'm told to allocate the memory for a connection and database using malloc(sizeof(struct xxxx)), like so:

```
struct Connection *conn = malloc(sizeof(struct Connection));
if(!conn) die("Memory error");

conn->db = malloc(sizeof(struct Database));
if(!conn->db) die("Memory error");
```

When I run the program, I get a Segmentation Fault, then after running it under valgrind, I get this error:

```
==5770== Command: ./ex17 db.dat c
==5770== 
==5770== Invalid read of size 1
==5770==    at 0x40C4130: _IO_file_fopen@@GLIBC_2.1 (fileops.c:267)
==5770==    by 0x40B88CA: __fopen_internal (iofopen.c:90)
==5770==    by 0x40B893A: fopen@@GLIBC_2.1 (iofopen.c:103)
==5770==    by 0x8048861: Database_open (ex17.c:58)
==5770==    by 0x8048C4C: main (ex17.c:156)
==5770==  Address 0x77 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
```

Line 156 in main is simply creating a new connection struct through a function `struct Connection *conn = Database_open(filename, action);`, and that doesn't seem to be the issue. Following it up to the line 58 in Database_open is `conn->file = fopen(filename, 'w');` From the not stack'd, malloc'd part of the error, I assumed the mallocs above were the issue. Can someone confirm/help me fix this?

[Full code](http://pastebin.com/G51GcWhD)

Comment: Considering the program should die with an error message if the `malloc`s failed, it's safe to say this piece of code isn't the problem.

Comment: The second parameter to `fopen` should be a string in double quotes, not a character constant: `fopen(filename, "w")`.

Comment: @MicroVirus is correct: the `malloc` calls aren't the problem. The traceback indicates that you're trying to use the value `0x77` as an address. `0x77` happens to be the ASCII value of the character `'w'`; does that ring a bell? Please update your question to include enough code to diagnose the problem; if necessary, narrow your program down to something small enough to post that still exhibits the problem.

Comment: In other words: your problem is a simple typo, and thus off topic. In the future, you might want to copy-paste code from the exercise into another file, and run diff between your typed version and the copy-pasted one.

Comment: @MOehm If you take a look at the actual exercise (more specifically at the `Database_open` function) you'll notice fopen is called correctly -- unless OP copied it wrong on his own machine.

Comment: @FlorinStingaciu ROODAY is typing those exercises in, I think that's one aspect of the pedagogical approach chosen in that online book. He made a typo while typing the program in.

Comment: @KubaOber I just noticed that he posted a link to his typed out full code base...

Comment: @FlorinStingaciu And that link shows the typo :)

Comment: It's basically a nice question, with sufficient detail to diagnose the problem, yet it's still off-topic here. There's a never ending supply of typos out there. It's not very likely that people will commit the same typo, or that if they do, they'll find this question. Never mind that the code clearly displayed in the code block is not the code that causes the problem.

Comment: oh wow. I just feel silly now. Thanks for pointing it out, I'll make sure to run a diff first next time!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is your `fopen` call. The `mode` is supposed to be a  string, not a `char`. Change the mode to `"r+"` or `"w"`.

Also, compile with more warnings enabled.

Comment: You figured that out from `Address 0x77` (with `0x77 == 'w'`) in the segfault dump? Nice!

Comment: @barakmanos: No I figured it out by looking at the stack trace. The program crashes when calling `fopen`. `fopen` is such a core function though, I knew it probably wasn't buggy. So I thought if it's crashing in `fopen`, but `fopen` isn't buggy, then perhaps the parameters being passed to it are wrong. I thought `filename` might be the culprit, but after reading the code, it didn't look suspect. There was only one other parameter being passed to `fopen`, so I looked at it, realized it was a char and not a string, and thought "Hmmm... I thought `fopen` took strings, not chars".

Comment: @barakmanos: (continued) A quick google search and brief [manual scan](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fopen.3.html) showed that yes, it should be a string, not a char. (I just wanted to share how I found the problem in the hopes that it might help you in debugging in the future)

Comment: Well, then you might as well add this notion to your answer. Function `fopen` expects an address of a null-terminated string as the second parameter, and OP has called it with `'w'` (which is equal 0x77) instead of `"w"`. BTW, it's not me who ran into this problem, I just expressed my impression of you being able to detect the `'w'` problem out of the stack trace, without having the actual buggy-code in front of you (assuming that you have indeed detected that issue).

Comment: @Cornstalks: I hope to one day have such debugging powers

Comment: @Cornstalks The explanation takes the magic away ;)